# How to execute several python scripts in parallel that use 2 GPUs and avoid cuda out of memory?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cuda, out-of-memory, xargs

I have a bash file (generateData.sh) that contains hundred of python scripts such as :

```
python create_video.py input output --param1 --param2 --param3
```

Each python script processes a different input video and uses in the process one of the two available GPU on my machine (for some computer vision tasks).

I tried to parallelize the bash file using GNU parallel (or xargs or &) with :

```
cat generateData.sh | parallel
```

This allows me to parallelize 48 python scripts. However, because of the limited space on GPU, only 10 of them correctly finish with a good output video. The other input videos are not handle at all, probably because it encountered some cuda out-of-memory errors.

I would like GPU parallel to wait that some jobs finish to have some free space on GPUs. Otherwise, GPU parallel will only process correctly a sub-part of my bash file.

Thanks for you answers !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
cat python-lines.sh |
  parallel -j48 CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='$(({%} % 2))' {=uq=}
```

to run 24 jobs per GPU on 2 CUDA devices.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer ! The thing is that I want to put more than 2 jobs on each GPU. For example I could put 5 videos on each GPU, but it depends on the size of the video.

Comment: @FlorianDelcour How du to force the computation onto GPU 2? How do you determine whether there is capacity on GPU 2 to run the next job on that?

Comment: Using nvidia-smi command, I can check the memory-usage of GPUs. For example a 720p video takes 1002MiB of space on the GPU so I can parallelize ~24 videos on 1 GPU of 24Go RAM. However, your solution looks quite nice but it doesn't work with my bash file. I got "No such file directory" for every lines of the bash file.

Comment: @FlorianDelcour Try: `{=uq=}` - see above (requires version 20190722 or later)